# Doctrine MongoDB rename reference field

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following reference in my class:

```
/**
 * @Expose
 * @Groups({"personal"})
 *
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="AppBundle\Document\Correspondence", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $archiveCorrespondences;
```

And I want to save this reference in my database under the name **archive_correspondences**
But whatever I did, doctrine always keeps it under **archiveCorrespondences**

I use the following:

1. php 7
2. mongodb 3.2
3. symfony 2.8
4. doctrine/mongodb-odm : dev-master
5. doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle: dev-master

From the doctrine mongodb documentation I did't find any possibilities, like for `@Field annotation`, where you can specify name.
By some reasons I can't rename `$archiveCorrespondences` to `$archive_correspondences` in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try `name` property. It should work for `ReferenceMany`:

```
/**
 * @Expose
 * @Groups({"personal"})
 *
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(name="archive_correspondences", targetDocument="AppBundle\Document\Correspondence", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $archiveCorrespondences;
```